# Not able to pull image from local docker registry when tried to create a POD using yaml file

Tags: image, docker, connection, containers, kubernetes

I'm not able to pull an image from my local docker registry when I try to create a POD using yaml file. Here are the diagnostic steps taken:

```
kubectl describe pod <pod name>
```

> error msg: Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5001/v1/repositories/hello_world_application/images: dial tcp [::1]:5001: getsockopt: connection refused

---

```
docker images
```

> REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE ID CREATED SIZE
>
> img_app latest 259dc6d7b6fe 18 hours ago 689.3 MB
>   localhost:5001/img_app latest 259dc6d7b6fe 18 hours ago 689.3 MB
>   docker.io/python 2.7 ca388cdb5ac1 8 days ago 676.1 MB

---

```
netstat -anp | grep 5001
```

> tcp6 0 0 :::5001 :::* LISTEN 31971/registry

---

Here's my `Pod` configuration (my-pod.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod-1
  labels:
    name: my-pod-label
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-application
    image: localhost:5001/img_app:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
      name: my-pod-label
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading through your debugging output, it seems that you have the images laying on your local docker host without running a [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). Therefore using `imagePullPolicy: Never` in your POD config would allow you to use the local images from the docker daemon without going the detour through an additional registry.